# Content type with webform

Tags: 7, webforms

Hi All I have I issue for my content type
like

1. I have content type  of property    user can add property fields
   this is  ok
2. My problem is  i have to add  static form every time . i want it
   default of every content  type is it possible please give me
   suggestion for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting in Webform "Available as block" so, it will be Available as block, you can use this block in all node pages

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me how  i display only it for content full mode not for node id for  a content type

Comment: what does that mean by node id? please provide detail information

Comment: i want like this http://prntscr.com/canon9

Comment: It is product full description  page so view mode of content type is full content so i need webform in this place

Comment: Well Nagarjuna thanks for your  help  i found the solution for this

Comment: on block setting restrict content to your content type thanks